# Scrapy Shell Doesn't Work and cant use commands

Tags: shell, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to use the [Scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) with this URL:

https://ueaeprints.uea.ac.uk/cgi/search/simple?screen=Public%3A%3AEPrintSearch&_action_search=Search&q_merge=ALL&q=fulltext&order=title%2Fcreators_name%2F-date

but it doesn't work. I get this:

```
[1] 7357
[2] 7358
[3] 7359
[4] 7360
```

and I can not write any command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the url inside apostrophes **'**http://url/name**'**:

```
scrapy shell 'https://ueaeprints.uea.ac.uk/cgi/search/simple?screen=Public%3A%3AEPrintSearch&_action_search=Search&q_merge=ALL&q=fulltext&order=title%2Fcreators_name%2F-date'
```